# Finding the line of a specific string and reading the text file after that line

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a text file (~20MB) from which I want to extract some information. The info I am interested in looks like this:

```
   Generate :
 MESH :     Cartesian
   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.84680   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.80724
 MESH : 4 unique points
               x           y           z        Weight
    1      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000     0.3906
    2      0.125000    0.000000    0.000000     0.7812
    3      0.250000    0.000000    0.000000     0.7812
    4      0.375000    0.000000    0.000000     0.7812
```

I want to save the x,y,z columns to an array after the second occurrence of the string 'MESH'.
I tried using regex, but my solution saves the result as a list and makes it too complicated to call these values for future purposes. Here is my attempt:

```
import re

line_number = 0
mesh_list = []
Qp = []
with open('out.test','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_number +=1
        if 'MESH' in line:
            mesh_list.append([(line_number),line.rstrip()])

point_info = mesh_list[1]
output_line = point_info[0]             ## Line number where MESH appears the second time.
point_list = point_info[1].split()
num_of_points = int(point_list[1])      ## Get number of unique points.

with open('out.test','r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if output_line+1 <= i <= output_line+num_of_points:
            Qp.append([line])

print(Qp)
```

At this point, 'Qp' has all the lines I need, but how can I separate x,y,z columns from this chunk? Would it be easier with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) with custom `skiprows=` and `sep=` parameters:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

r = re.compile(r"MESH : \d+ unique points")

line_counter = 0
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for l in f_in:
        line_counter += 1
        if r.search(l):
            break

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.txt", skiprows=line_counter, sep=r"\s+")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       x    y    z  Weight
1  0.000  0.0  0.0  0.3906
2  0.125  0.0  0.0  0.7812
3  0.250  0.0  0.0  0.7812
4  0.375  0.0  0.0  0.7812
```

Comment: Hi, this looks very elegant, but I'm getting this error:
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: @user175924 Make sure the regex is correct (correct number of spaces etc.). Probably the regex `"MESH : \d+ unique points"` wasn't found and pandas skips all rows.

Comment: The problem occurs because skiprows=line_counter. Your for loop doesn't break when it finds the string defined in r, so it reads all the lines, and in df, skips all lines and there's nothing left to read. When I use the part of my code where I got the line number (output_line), it gives me the correct result. What would be the problem?

Comment: @user175924 There's a `break` when the regex finds successful match. Apparently, there's some difficulty with the regex `MESH : \d+ unique points`. I don't have the exact file you have, so I cannot pinpoint the problem. But you can use solution without regex - just find second "MESH" in your file and break.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, my bad. There was a slight difference on that line. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To get `x`, `y`, `z` (line number and `Weight`) from `Qp`, which is a list of one-element lists, as `tuple`s (converting the `tuple`s to `list`s is trivial) you can try:

```py
>>> Qp
[['    1      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000     0.3906\n'], ['    2      0.125000    0.000000    0.000000     0.7812\n'], ['    3      0.250000    0.000000    0.000000     0.7812\n'], ['    4      0.375000    0.000000    0.000000     0.7812\n']]

>>> lno, x, y, z, Weight  = zip(*(line[0].split() for line in Qp))
>>> lno
('1', '2', '3', '4')
>>> x
('0.000000', '0.125000', '0.250000', '0.375000')
>>> y
('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
>>> z
('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
>>> Weight
('0.3906', '0.7812', '0.7812', '0.7812')
```

For `float`s instead of `str`s:

```py
>>> lno, x, y, z, Weight = zip(*((float(a) for a in line[0].split()) for line in Qp))
```

To get `x`, `y`, `z` (and `Weight`) as columns of a dataframe:

```py
>>> import pandas
>>> import re
>>>
>>> with open('out.test','r') as f:
...     for i, line in enumerate(f,1):
...         m = re.search('MESH : (\d+) unique points', line)
...         if m:
...             break
...
>>> i
6
>>> m.group(1)
'4'
>>> df = pd.read_csv('out.test', skiprows=i, nrows=int(m.group(1))+1, sep=r"\s+")
>>> df
       x    y    z  Weight
1  0.000  0.0  0.0  0.3906
2  0.125  0.0  0.0  0.7812
3  0.250  0.0  0.0  0.7812
4  0.375  0.0  0.0  0.7812
```